# How can I scroll to a an id/anchor on another page?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, hyperlink, onload

I have a link in my nav that, when clicked, directs you to the home page and scrolls down to a certain section via id. When I call a function on the click of the link it will direct to the new page but not scroll anywhere. Since the function has to be asynchronous it won't do what I'm trying to do.

My HTML

```
<a id="categoryButton"><li>Categories</li></a>
<!-- further down the page -->
<div id="categoryTitleDiv"><h1 id="categoryTitle">Where I want to scroll to</h1></div>
```

My JS

```
document.getElementById("categoryButton").onclick = function onCategoryButtonClick() {
    window.location.href = "</*my page address*/";
      document.getElementById("categoryTitleDiv").scrollIntoView();
    }
```

The problem with this is that since they are synchronous the commands happen at the same time. So I end up on the right page from `window.location.href = "</*my page address*/";` but I don't scroll anywhere.

Then I tried to learn about Promises but I'm not sure I'm doing it right. I REALLY thought this would work but it just leaves me with the same problem as before. They seem to still run synchronously and I will just get to the new page.

```
document.getElementById("categoryButton").onclick = function() {
  const promise = new Promise(function onCategoryButtonClick(resolve, reject) {
    const clickedVar = true;
    if (clickedVar) {
      window.location.href = "/*my page address*/";
      console.log("yay");
      resolve();
    } else {
      console.log("nay");
      reject();
    }
  });

  promise.then(function(){
    document.getElementById("categoryTitleDiv").scrollIntoView();
  }, function(){
    console.log("What the heck happened?");
  });
}
```

I've tested a couple of other things too like setTimeout (though that isn't ideal) but that didn't work either. I think because it wanted to scroll to a part of the original page and not the newly loaded page. But I am not great at Javascript so I'm probably very wrong. Another thing I tried was calling a window.onload function and using that to execute the scroll code but that left me with the same result as all the others, I make it to the page but it scrolls no where. Here's the code for that

```
  window.location.href = "/*my page address*/";
  window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("categoryTitleDiv").scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

Overall I am very frustrated and cannot for the life of me figure this out. Thanks all, stay safe!

Comment: Promises aren't going to help you. Each page has its own javascript environment, completely replacing the previous page's environment. If you want something to run in the new page, then it must be js loaded with that page. The good news is that you don't need javascript at all. Good old fashioned hyperlinks in combination with an appropriately formed `<a/>` tag will do what you want. Try searching for "fragment identifier".

Comment: AHHH it was so simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a push in the right direction from a comment from *https://stackoverflow.com/users/3478010/roamer-1888* I have figured it out. I just made the `href` of my link go to the desired page and added "#categoryTitleDiv" to the end of the web address. So it looks like

`<a href="...\website name\index.html#categoryTitleDiv"><li>Categories</li></a>` It's not smooth scrolling but it works!

Comment: If it's important, I'm sure there's a way to smooth-scroll. A jQuery plugin maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement a navigation to a specific section on another page using a hash in the link: ( ... / { article.link } # { article.id } ).

To achieve this, I needed to use the method - getBoundingClientRect(), which returns a DOMRect object providing information about the position of the desired element relative to the viewport.

However, if there is a lot of content on the destination page, getBoundingClientRect() executes faster than the content loads, resulting in the scroll not reaching the intended section.

In the end, I was able to solve this by adding timeouts to both getBoundingClientRect() and the scroll to the element.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (articles.length === 0) return;  // Wait for the articles to load
    const hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); // Extract the hash from the path
    const scrollElement = document.getElementById(hash);
    if (scrollElement) {
      setTimeout(()=>{            //(1)
        const { top } = scrollElement.getBoundingClientRect();
             setTimeout(() => {   //(2)
        window.scrollTo({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          top: top + (window.scrollY || document.documentElement.scrollTop) - 100,
        });
      }, 300); //(2) Add delay for scrolling
      }, 300); //(1) Add delay for obtaining getBoundingClientRect
    }
  }, [articles]);
```